# Why am I receiving error http 403 forbidden?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have just made a change to an Xpages application successfully on our development instance on the notes development server.  I have deployed the change to out Train instance application on our notes train server for testing by the application administrator.  We create an application design template of the development instance and use this to replace the design of the train instance.  This usually goes very well but this time after I have cleaned and built the Train instance and I attempt to open it in the browser I am presented with the error;

http 403 fobidden. And below it states - most likely cause "the website requires you to login", even though I have logged in.  What will be causing this to occur?

I have backtracked to a backup of the previous Train instance and it works fine.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience this is because the xpage is signed by an ID that is not listed in the "Sign agents or XPages to run on behalf of the invoker" on the security tab of the server document, so might be worth checking there?

Comment: Thanks.  This could be an answer because while developing the solution on the Development instance it included an Agent that had to be signed by the server ID - I think the entire DB was sihned by the server ID.  Will investigate how to resolve.  Do I have the Train DB instance signed by the server ID?

Comment: You dont HAVE to sign it with the server ID. This will resolve the issue by the sounds of it, however the option above will do the same job.

I prefer adding my name to the server document, this saves having to re-sign a database with another ID when you refresh the live copy from your DEV template, and also keeps the modified time stamps on design elements intact....

Comment: Thanks. I manged to get into the Administration Console and resign the "Development" instance with the Developer ID and everything worked in the Development instance.  I then redeployed to the Train instance and the http 403 error is now resolved.  However, an agent I created with my deployed solution does not run when I schedule it.  Why would that be?

Comment: Could be a number of things......

a) Did the agent actually run? Check the agent log. If it says it did, then it means it definitely ran, but encountered an error a terminated early, not completing its function.

b) What is the agents runtime security level?

c) If testing in your DEV environment, when you refreshed the live copy, you may have to update the Run on (server) setting to the correct server?

d) Do you have any error handling in your agent? Is anything printed out?

Comment: Thanks again.  Found issue.  When redeploying to Train I forgot to change the value of the server in the Agents properties.  Ooops!!!  Thank you

Comment: I only answered with that as a possibility as I've done it many times before myself! Glad you're all good now